# Use quickCheck tests with Cabal?

Tags: testing, haskell, cabal

What's the current state of test suites in cabal, and, more importantly, where can I keep atop them?

I've done some poking around, and the latest information that I can find implies that [I can't trust the documentation](http://www.mail-archive.com/cabal-devel@haskell.org/msg07616.html), and I haven't been able to find anyone talking about it for the better part of a year. I've heard rumor of a `cabal-test-quickcheck` library but can't seem to find one on hackage and can find no examples of how to set it up.

What's the standard way to hook up quickCheck tests into a cabal test suite these days?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Cabal-1.14.0.0` has come out since then and the detailed test suite [seems to be available](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Cabal/1.14.0/doc/html/Distribution-TestSuite.html).

The `cabal-test-quickcheck` package doesn't seem to have been released yet though, maybe you can get similar functionality from [test-framework-quickcheck2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework-quickcheck2)?

Alternatively, you can ignore the inbuilt test support in Cabal and just use a flag to determine whether or not to build a test executable.

Comment: I've had good results with `test-framework`, so much that I can't believe that the Cabal people are completely wasting their time reinventing it when they need to just use it for the test-suites! Just use the `simple` test suite with a hook into the main from `test-framework`.